# using regex to find literal strings in a text

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import re
code1 = '''
b = -9
a = b + c
year = 2000
month = 0xA
date = 0b1101
sec = 1.8E3
d_1 = year + month
d_2 = date * sec
err = 0o0.1
'''
```

I am given this text and I have to extract all the literal strings from here. I was using the split method and made great progress but I do not know how to express literal strings. I found out I could use regex.

Can anyone help me make a regular expression that will extract only the literal strings in this text?

```
lst_str = ['b', 'a','c', 'year', 'month'. 'date', 'sec', 'd_1','d_2', 'err']
```

Comment: This contains no "literal strings" - do you mean identifiers? Regex is the wrong tool, you should use the `ast` module from the standard library. https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

Comment: can we assume all the litterals are always left from the '=' signs ?

Comment: Just a heads up, as @kaya3 mentioned string literals are strings of characters enclosed in quotes such as `"Hello"` and `"World"`. Your string you provided does not contain any string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the string provided above ie.,

```
code1 = '''
b = -9
a = b + c
year = 2000
month = 0xA
date = 0b1101
sec = 1.8E3
d_1 = year + month
d_2 = date * sec
err = 0o0.1
'''
```

and regex:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\s+([A-Za-z]+[_\d]*)")
match = pattern.findall(code1)
```

output on print(match):

```
['b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'year', 'month', 'date', 'sec', 'd_1', 'year', 'month', 'd_2', 'date', 'sec', 'err']
```

Breaking down the Regex:

- `\s+` - Matches 1 or more Unicode whitespace characters (which includes [ \t\n\r\f\v]
- `()` - Encloses the part of the matching string that we need to display or use further.
- `[A-Za-z]+` - Matches a sequence of upper case and/or lower case letters with the sequence length at least 1 (1 or more).
- `[_\d]*` - Matches a sequence of underscores and/or digits(0-9) with sequence length as 0 or more i.e., underscore or digit may or may not be trailing the letters.

You can refer the official doc for regex in python to know more about the **special sequences** used - [Python Regex Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions like this:

```
import re

code1 = '''
b = -9
a = b + c
year = 2000
month = 0xA
date = 0b1101
sec = 1.8E3
d_1 = year + month
d_2 = date * sec
err = 0o0.1
'''

pattern = re.compile(r"\b([a-z]+[a-z0-9_]*)\b")
match = pattern.findall(code1)
```

You get:

```
['b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'year', 'month', 'date', 'sec', 'd_1', 'year', 'month', 'd_2', 'date', 'sec', 'err']
```

If you want to avoid multiple occurrences you can use a set:

```
list(set(match))
```

and you get:

```
['sec', 'month', 'a', 'd_1', 'b', 'c', 'year', 'date', 'err', 'd_2']
```

I am not sure if I understood your request though.